# Connecting a Panasonic EVQ-VVD00203B radial encoder to Arduino

Tags: arduino, encoder

I purchased this Panasonic EVQ-VVD00203B radial encoder for an Arduino project, and am having difficulty figuring out out to wire everything up. This is the encoder:

[image: Panasonic EVQ-VVD00203B radial encoder]

If I understand the schematic correctly, the top is 5V, the bottom left and right are signal A and B, which I should be able to connect to two separate digital ins in order to capture rotation amount and direction through phase difference between them. But the bottom center doesn't say "ground" or "-". It says "COM". I thought this meant common ground, but whenever I connect a ground to it, it shorts the arduino. Here is a screenshot of the test circuit form the wiring diagram:

[image: wiring diagram]

And here is how I currently have it wired up. I have power going to 5V, COM going to ground, bottom-left going to digital6, and botton-right going to digital7.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?[

Comment: Your schematic shows three connections to the encoder but your picture shows 4. What is the red wire doing?

Comment: Power. I got the top COM confused with +5V in the wiring diagram. As I now understand, I may have fried my first encoder.

Comment: The encoder should be ok - the com is probably man enough to take the small current available from the Arduino. There’s many tutorials on hooking  a mechanical encoder to the Arduino. You might want to seek them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The datasheet shows the two terminals on the centerline of the encoder are COM and the ones to the side are A and B.  As @Justme says, the resistors, supply, etc are supposed to be provided by you.  The 10k to +5V provides the pullup, the other 10k and capacitor provide some filtering since this is a mechanical encoder and some noise is to be expected.  What you could do, however, is enable the internal pullups on the digital pins of your Arduino and write your program to debounce the inputs in software, no external parts necessary.

Hooking up +5V to one of the COM terminals and grounding the other one may have burned out some internal connection so it's possible that one or both of your COM terminals are now unusable.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The encoder has 4 pins but only 3 different terminals, A, COM and B at the bottom, and another COM terminal pin at the top.

So by connecting 5V to one common terminal and GND to the other common terminal, it is just a piece of wire that shorts 5V and GND together.

The 5V does not connect to the encoder at all. The encoder is represented as the 3 pin box and all the resistors as well as the 5V supply is external to the encoder.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me.